# JPA return null for hibernate mapping in api response

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, rest, jpa, spring-data-jpa

tbl_user_content table am storing the country id. in my response i have show the country name from the  tbl_country table,

1. Entity-> A

```
@Setter
@Getter
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@DynamicInsert
@Table(name = "tbl_user_content")
public class ContentManage implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2526575458651174224L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "user_content_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name= "user_content_generator", sequenceName = "tbl_user_content_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name ="id")
    private  int id;

    @Column(name = "position")
    private  int position;

    @Column(name = "title")
    private  String title;

    @Column(name = "shortdescription")
    private  String shortdescription;

    @Column(name = "thumbnailimage")
    private  String thumbnailimage;

    @Column(name = "linkactions")
    private  String linkactions;

    @Column(name = "last_updated_date")
    private ZonedDateTime last_updated_date;

    @Column(name = "last_updated_by")
    private  String last_updated_by;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "countryid", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    private Country country;

}
```

2. Entity -> B

```
@Setter
@Getter
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@DynamicInsert
@Table(name = "tbl_country")
public class Country implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2526575458651174224L;

    @Id
    @Column(name ="id")
    private  String countryId;

    @Column(name = "created_dt")
    private ZonedDateTime created_date;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private  String countryName;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = ContentManage.class, mappedBy = "country", orphanRemoval = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<ContentManage> contentManage;

}
```

Service class

```
public ContentManageVO queryContenetManage(int contentmanageId) {
        System.out.println("contentmanageid value==="+contentmanageId);
        Optional<ContentManage> contentManageOptional = contentManageRepository.findById(contentmanageId);
        ContentManage contentManage = contentManageOptional
                .orElseThrow(() -> new GenericBadException(StaffNotificationExceptionEnum.CONTENT_MANAGE_NOT_FOUND_EXCEPTION));
        ContentManageVO contentManageVO = new ContentManageVO();
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(contentManage, contentManageVO);
        return contentManageVO;
    }
```

API response : country id returns null

```
{
"id": 17,
"position": 123,
"title": "title",
"shortDescription": "shortdescription",
"thumbnailimage": "thumbnailimage",
"linkactions": "linkactions",
"last_updated_date": "2021-02-23T14:02:42.891+08",
"last_updated_by": "last_updated_by",
"countryid": null
```

}

please any one suggest

[while debug I can find the country entity have the value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlzFV.jpg)

[but response entity unable set the value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtOV8.jpg)

Comment: I am not seeing any relationship between your entities. Your ContentManage only has a reference to the entity Country but they don;t actually hold any relationship other than you tagging it with JoinColumn.

Comment: when I used the @query parameter (inner join script) am getting this error"stack_trace":"java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast

Comment: refer the below: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66490776/java-lang-classcastexception-ljava-lang-object-cannot-be-cast-or-beanutils-co